# Why is the color of my button which is bind to an element of a brush array is not showing in the UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am trying to change button's color when it is clicked. But It's not changing color. Here is my code.

```
private SolidColorBrush[] _btnBrush;
        public SolidColorBrush[] btnBrush
        {
            get
            {
                return _btnBrush;
            }
            set
            {
                _btnBrush = value; OnPropertyChanged("btnBrush");
            }
        }

     public MineViewModel()
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
             btnBrush[i] = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#EED6C4");
}
```

the method which button is bind to

```
public void LeftClick(string id_no)
        {
          btnBrush[Convert.ToInt32(id_no)] = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#B3541E");
        }
```

and for XAML

```
<Button x:Name="btn4" Background="{Binding btnBrush[3]}" Command="{Binding LeftClickCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
```

This is executing correctly, the element in array also got the color. But it won't show on the UI.
If I bind it with a single solid brush, it works. But not with array of brushes.
Any help?

Comment: Just in case, declaring 100 Buttons in XAML is not exactly a great approach. Consider using an ItemsControl. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
btnBrush[i] = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#B3541E");
```

does not change the value of the `btnBrush` property. It does not even call the property setter.

You may however change the `Color` property of the SolidColorBrush at element index `i`, like

```
btnBrush[i].Color = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#B3541E");
```

This will notify the UI because `Color` is a dependency property. Otherwise the array element type would have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire a change notification.

Comment: I thought that you normally suggest to use ItemsControl in cases like this?

Comment: @ASh In a future post. They are learning step by step.